# How can i make stylesheet-path dynamically?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying an XSLT transform from within my javacode. I want to make  stylesheet-path dinamically. But I can't get it working with the param $path.How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

java.code

```
transformation.setParameter("path", "C:\Users\src");
```

transformation.xsl

```
 <xsl:param path="path"/>
  <xsl:include href="$path/config.xsl"/>
```

Comment: a missing colon after "C"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URIs to reference external resources. Try this:

```
transformation.setParameter("path", "file:///C:/Users/src");
```

Note that relative paths work in XSLT. There may be no need to pass in an absolute path at all.

Comment: I've read that: It is illegal to have a variable reference in the href attribute of <xsl:include>